# DeprecationWarning and NoSuchElementException when automating Twitter login using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, twitter, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am trying to automate the process of logging into Twitter using Selenium in Python. However, I am encountering two issues: a DeprecationWarning and a NoSuchElementException. Here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Automating the process of opening the Twitter login page
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")

# Variables to store your credentials
email = "your-email-address"
password = "your-password"

# Copy the updated XPaths of the email field, password field, and login button
email_xpath = '/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input'
password_xpath = '/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/label/div/div[2]/div[1]/input'
login_xpath = '/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div'

# Find email field, password field, and login button using XPaths
email_field = driver.find_element('xpath', email_xpath)
password_field = driver.find_element('xpath', password_xpath)
login_button = driver.find_element('xpath', login_xpath)

email_field.send_keys(email)
password_field.send_keys(password)

time.sleep(1)

login_button.click()
```

However, I am getting the following error messages:

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adwai\OneDrive\Desktop\twitter- automation\app.py", line 19, in <module>
    email_field = driver.find_element('xpath', email_xpath)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adwai\OneDrive\Desktop\twitter- automation\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 831, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adwai\OneDrive\Desktop\twitter- automation\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\adwai\OneDrive\Desktop\twitter- automation\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672

.127)
Stacktrace:
...
```

How can I resolve these issues and successfully automate the Twitter login process using Selenium?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this way:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = "https://twitter.com/i/flow/login"
driver.get(url)

username = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[autocomplete="username"]')))
username.send_keys("YOUR USERNAME")
username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

password = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="password"]')))
password.send_keys("YOUR PASSWORD")
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(10)
```